# Azure Pipeline fails when * in version of package config

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

When building in VS with config

```
<PackageReference Include="<PackageName>" Version="*" />
```

Does works fine.
When building using a Azue Devops Pipeline.

This fails

```
<PackageReference Include="<PackageName>" Version="*" />
```

##[error].csproj(0,0): Error NU1101: Unable to find package . No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

This succeeds

```
<PackageReference Include="<PackageName>" Version="2023.4.4.3" />
```

Any suggestions ?